# how to set workspace of Geoprocessor in .net?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I am migrating some code from VBA to C# for developing an addin. In VBA, the geoprocessor's workspace could easily be accessed by workspace property of Geoprocessor. But how to set the geoprocessor's Workspace property in .NET environment

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1207/files/gp_arcobjects.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can go through following links:

1. [Using ArcObjects as tool input](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000041n000000)
2. [Using environment settings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001n5000000)
3. [IGeoProcessor2 Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n000000tq000000)